# Flutter Grid Modal Bottom Sheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

i want to make a modal but all the examples i find should be horizontally sorted vertically as in this code

```
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
                  ),
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.email),
                          title: Text('Send email'),
                          onTap: () {
                            print('Send email');
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
                          title: Text('Call phone'),
                          onTap: () {
                            print('Call phone');
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.email),
                          title: Text('Send email'),
                          onTap: () {
                            print('Send email');
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

In this code, it lists vertically, I want it to be sorted horizontally, as in the photo.

[image]

Comment: instead of column try with wrap with spacing or use griview

Comment: thanks 
gridview.count()
I made it using the widget